# gnupg integration with openLDAP - ACL Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap, country

**Please could you help me resolving this error with OpenLDAP?**

```
### ldif - To change ACL  ######

# userPassword may be written only by users themselves
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
# Allow access via localhost to add or modify keys.
# Allow authenticated PGP Users to update keys.
# Allow anyone else to read the keys.
olcAccess: {2} to dn.subtree="ou=PGP Keys,dc=example,dc=net"
 by peername.ip=127.0.0.1 write
 by peername.ip=:: write
 by dn.regex="^uid=([^,]+),ou=PGP Users,dc=example,dc=net" write by * read
# Allow any connection to localhost to update the PGP keys
# (including removing them!)  This is only needed if the anonymous
# updates from localhost are desired.
dn: cn=config
add: olcAllows
olcAllows: update_anon
```

## -----------------------------------------

When i try to modify/add it with

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/keyserver-acl.ldif
```

or

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/keyserver-acl.ldif
```

doesn't go through, it always prompts an irritating error of Wrong attributeType

> ****** Error
>
> root@keyserver:/tmp# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f
>   /tmp/keyserver-acl.ldif SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started SASL
>   username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth SASL
>   SSF: 0 ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 5, entry
>   "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a blank line before the `dn: cn=config` line.